# SoapClient not returning the result it should

Tags: php, soap, soapui, soap-client

When I test this WSDL with SoapUI, then I get real result, it just adds to numbers:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl");

$result = $client->add(3,3);

print_r($result);
```

This returns :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => 0
)
```

**But should return 6.** As it does in SoapUI.

Some debugging:

```
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());

Array
(
    [0] => addResponse add(add $parameters)
)
Array
(
    [0] => struct add {
         int arg0;
         int arg1;
    }
    [1] => struct addResponse {
         int return;
    }
)
```

Comment: Instantiate `SoapClient` with `trace` option set to true, and compare `$client->__getLastRequest();` with xml send by soapui.

Comment: use nusoap :) eventually you'll have to anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addResponse` Expects only one parameter, so you need to pass it in array or an object:

```
$params = array(
    'arg0' => 3,
    'arg1' => 3
);

//OR
//$params = new stdClass;
//$params->arg0 = 3;
//$params->arg1 = 3;

$result = $client->add($params);
```